# Choosing what View to load when App goes back to foreground

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, appdelegate

How can I choose which ViewController my App should load when the app goes back to foreground?

- Is it by default the last view used in the App?
- Is there a way to choose a different view or viewcontroller? If so
  how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:
[Apple Documentation-UIAppDelegate-applicationWillEnterForeground](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:)

to change your window rootViewController property :)
So basically, you could instantiate your view controller in this method(from storyboard, or all in code), and do the following:

`self.window.rootViewController = yourVc`

Answer (score 0):

By default, your last view is the one shown by your application.
If you want to change it to another view (for example a lock screen view), you must change your **window.rootViewController** inside your ApplicationDelegate code, inside both

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```